# Ubuntu 12.04 startup is slow and dmesg output seems to lose several seconds

Tags: 12.04, boot, plymouth

I use ubuntu on Dell Inspiron n4050.I have upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04. 
But now I find the system startup is a little slow and plymouth only show purple screen without logo during startup.

When I use dmesg, it shows such messages:

    `[    2.497750] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [    2.603028] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
    [    2.715538] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
    [    2.715594] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    [    2.715596] USB Mass Storage support registered.
    [   21.317843] Adding 2000892k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2000892k
    [   21.323724] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [   21.391450] udevd[431]: starting version 175`

I wonder what it is doing between 2 second and 21 second. Is it related to being so slow?

I tried bootchart. It gave me a complex picture. Sorry I can't post it here.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_U5quEFRFT_a2k1WEZPOEU1Mm8

While ubuntu is booting , I also noticed that it appears:`/tmp is not ready or present` And sometimes follows `*Stop saving kernel messages`. Is this the reason dmesg lost output?

Answer (score 0):

Try install `bootchart` to figure out bottleneck, where the time gap is spent.

http://www.bootchart.org